# Golang HTML insert new line after a comma

Tags: go

I'm so nearly there - my last step is to insert a new line after a comma (where there is one).  For example, I have a table:

| Country | City | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mexico | Playa Del Carmen | 05-12-2019,06-12-2019,07-12-2019,08-12-2019,09-12-2019 |
| French Polynesia | Papeete | 16-11-2019 |

Rather than having all the dates on one line I want to insert a new line after each comma or better still replace the comma with a new line as below:

| Country | City | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mexico | Playa Del Carmen | 05-12-2019 |
| ignore | ignore | 06-12-2019 |
| ignore | ignore | 07-12-2019 |
| ignore | ignore | 08-12-2019 |
| ignore | ignore | 09-12-2019 |
| French Polynesia | Papeete | 16-11-2019 |

It doesn't need to be separate rows it can just be a list within the one row. The code I am using in golang html is:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th><b>Country</b></th>
            <th><b>City</b></th>
            <th><b>Dates</b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <ul>
                {{ range .TourCountry }}
                   <li>{{ . }}</li>
                {{ end }}
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                {{ range .TourCity }}
                    <li>{{ . }}</li>
                {{ end }}
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                {{ range .TourDateString }}
                    <li>{{ . }}</li>
                {{ end }}
              </ul>
            </td>
        </table>
```

The code I am using in the main.go file is:

```
func main() {
    // static folder
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    http.HandleFunc("/", mainPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/concert", concertPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/tour", tourPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", aboutPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/locations", locationsPage)

    port := ":8080"
    fmt.Println("Server listen on port localhost:8080")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen and Serve", err)
    }
}

func tourPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    listOfIds := r.URL.Query()["id"]
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(listOfIds[0])
    if err != nil {
        handle500(w)
    }

    ArtistsFull, _, _, _, _, _, _, err := GetData()
    if err != nil || len(ArtistsFull) == 0 {
        if err == nil {
            err = errors.New("empty ArtistsFull from GetData")
        }
        fmt.Printf("GetData() error: %+v", err)
        handle500(w)
    }
    artist, err := GetFullDataByID(id, ArtistsFull)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("GetFullDataByID(%d) error: %+v", id, err)
        handle400(w)
    }

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("tour.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("tour.html, error: %+v", err)
        handle500(w)
    }

    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, artist); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Tour Page Execute(w, artist) (%v) error: %+v/n", artist, err)
        handle500(w)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the comma separated string in Go and then pass the resulting slice to the template. Or you can add custom template functions (with [`Funcs`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template@go1.17.8#Template.Funcs)) that split the string in the template and then you can use that custom function within the template. Or you can define a method on the `.` value's type that does the split and then call that method within the template. As you can see you have at least 3 options, choose which ever you like best.

```golang
type Data struct {
    TourDateString []string
}

var template_file = `<td>
    <ul>
        {{ range .TourDateString }}
        <li>{{ . }}</li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</td>`

func main() {
    slice := strings.Split("05-12-2019,06-12-2019,07-12-2019,08-12-2019,09-12-2019", ",")
    data := Data{slice}

    t := template.Must(template.New("t").Parse(template_file))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/jx8u7dr8-G_z

```golang
type Data struct {
    TourDateString string
}

var template_file = `<td>
    <ul>
        {{ range (split .TourDateString ",") }}
        <li>{{ . }}</li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</td>`

func main() {
    data := Data{"05-12-2019,06-12-2019,07-12-2019,08-12-2019,09-12-2019"}

    t := template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "split": strings.Split,
    }).Parse(template_file))

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/IYqzF82WGgO

```golang
type Data struct {
    TourDateString string
}

func (d Data) SplitTourDateString() []string {
    return strings.Split(d.TourDateString, ",")
}

var template_file = `<td>
    <ul>
        {{ range .SplitTourDateString }}
        <li>{{ . }}</li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</td>`

func main() {
    data := Data{"05-12-2019,06-12-2019,07-12-2019,08-12-2019,09-12-2019"}

    t := template.Must(template.New("t").Parse(template_file))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Fnr42ZbvlfH

Comment: Thank you for this - I did try and incorporate but it isn't quite working out most likely I'm doing it all wrong.  I've edited my question showing what I want and the code I am using.  The dates were originally in a [][]string, however to stop them from printing in square brackets I changed them to a []string now just want to deal with the formatting so it doesn't all print in one line.